# Tensor product of measure spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, tensor-products

For a compact topological space $X$, denote by $\mathcal{M}(X)$ the Banach space of finite signed Borel (Radon) measures on $X$ with the total variation norm. This is canonically isometric to the dual space of the space of continuous functions $C(X)$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are compact spaces, then we have the isometric isomorphism
$$\mathcal{M}(X) \hat{\otimes}_\pi \mathcal{M}(Y) \cong \mathcal{M}(X \times Y),$$
where on the left side, we have the completed projective tensor product (*Side question: Does anybody know a reference for this statement? I only found the corresponding statement for the subspaces $L^1$, although the proof is very similar*). 
**[EDIT: this claim is incorrect in general -- see below]**

Now of course, one can also complete with respect to the injective tensor product, where the norm is given by
$$\varepsilon(z) = \sup_{\xi, \eta} \bigl\{ (\xi \otimes \eta)(z) \mid \xi \in \mathcal{M}(X)^\prime, \eta \in \mathcal{M}(X)^\prime, \|\xi\| = \|\eta\| = 1\bigr\}$$
for $z \in \mathcal{M}(X) \otimes \mathcal{M}(Y)$ (the algebraic tensor product). However, since the measure space are dual spaces, there is also a third alternative, namely
$$\tilde{\varepsilon}(z) = \sup_{f, g} \bigl\{ z(f \otimes g) \mid f \in C(X), g \in C(Y), \|f\| = \|g\| = 1\bigr\}.$$
Notice that (at least formally), the latter a much smaller norm, since die dual space of $\mathcal{M}(X)$ are huge. It seems to me that here we have the isomorphism
$$\mathcal{M}(X)\hat{\otimes}_{\tilde{\varepsilon}} \mathcal{M}(Y) \cong B\bigl(C(X) \times C(Y)\bigr),$$
with the space of bounded bilinear maps on $C(X) \times C(Y)$. Is this correct?

In any case, we have the inclusions
$$\mathcal{M}(X) \hat{\otimes}_\pi \mathcal{M}(Y) \subseteq \mathcal{M}(X)\hat{\otimes}_{{\varepsilon}} \mathcal{M}(Y) \subseteq \mathcal{M}(X)\hat{\otimes}_{\tilde{\varepsilon}} \mathcal{M}(Y)$$

**Now the questions:**

- Is there a characterization of the middle space?
- Are there "good" (i.e. somewhat natural examples) that show that this inclusion is in fact strict?

---

**Edit:** As Yemon Choi notices, I was possibly wrong by claiming that $\mathcal{M}(X) \hat{\otimes}_\pi \mathcal{M}(Y) \cong \mathcal{M}(X \times Y)$; in fact, it is only clear that it is an isometrically embedded subspace. Furthermore, by the comment of Matthew Daws, we have $\varepsilon = \tilde{\varepsilon}$.

**Edit2:** Thanks to the answers below, we obtain the following picture: First, we have
$$ \mathcal{M}(X) \hat{\otimes}_\varepsilon \mathcal{M}(Y) \cong \mathcal{M}(X) \hat{\otimes}_{\tilde{\varepsilon}} \mathcal{M}(Y),$$
using [the fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem) that the inclusion of the closed unit ball of $C(X)$ into the closed unit ball of $\mathcal{M}^\prime(X)$ is dense with respect to the weak-$*$-topology on $\mathcal{M}^\prime(X)$. From this follows that the norms $\varepsilon(z)$ and $\tilde{\varepsilon}(z)$ coincide.

Now due to the great answer by Matthew Daws below, the diagonal measure $\mu \in \mathcal{M}([0, 1]^2$ is an example of an element which is not contained in $\mathcal{M}([0, 1]) \hat{\otimes}_\varepsilon \mathcal{M}([0, 1])$, hence neither in $\mathcal{M}([0, 1]) \hat{\otimes}_\pi \mathcal{M}([0, 1])$.

In fact studying some literature tells me that $\mathcal{M}(X \times Y)$ can be identified with the subset of *integral forms* of $\mathrm{Bil}(C(X) \times C(Y))$. However, it is not yet clear to me yet whether every element of $\mathcal{M}(X) \hat{\otimes}_\varepsilon \mathcal{M}(Y)$ is actually integral, i.e. contained in $\mathcal{M}(X, Y)$, and whether the inclusion
$$\mathrm{Bil}(C(X) \times C(Y)) \supseteq \mathcal{M}(X \times Y)$$
is really a proper inclusion.

Comment: In your first paragraph, you need a word like "Radon" or "regular" or maybe "metrizable"...

Comment: $\epsilon$ and $\overline\epsilon$ always agree, for any (dual) Banach spaces.  Good references here are Diestel and Uhl's book on Vector Measures, or a personal favourite, Ryan's book "Introduction to tensor products of Banach spaces".  The proof is basically just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem   The _projective_ tensor product linearises bilinear maps, so I think (unless I misunderstand) that $B(C(X)\times C(Y))$ is $M(X) \hat\otimes_\pi M(Y)$.

Comment: @MatthewDaws Are you sure about that last one? If $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets of size $n$ then $M(X)\hat\otimes_\pi M(Y)$ is just $\ell_1^{n^2}$. But the bilinear functionals on $\ell_\infty^n$ should not have the same norm as the linear functionals on $\ell_\infty^{n^2}$ ...

Comment: Question for the OP: I agree that $M(X)\hat\otimes_\pi M(Y)$ should embed isometrically inside $M(X\times Y)$ but I don't see why we should get equality for, say, $X=Y=[0,1]$.

Comment: @YemonChoi: Yes, of course!  So, correctly, the bounded bilinear maps on $C(X)\times C(Y)$ is just the bounded linear maps $C(X)\hat\otimes_\pi C(Y) \rightarrow \mathbb C$, i.e. the dual space, which we can identify with the bounded linear map $C(X)\rightarrow C(Y)^* = M(Y)$. Thus $M(X) \hat\otimes_\epsilon M(Y)$ is in general only a subspace (it gives you just the compact maps $C(X)\rightarrow M(Y)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Please see the edits above.

Comment: Regarding the 2nd edit: if by Bil you mean all bilinear maps, then this space is sometimes known as the space of _bimeasures_. It is known in the theory of Banach spaces that not every bimeasure on $X\times Y$ is a measure (in the literature, this is often mentioned alongside results such as _Grothendieck's inequality_ ). I don't recall if this fact is in the book of Ryan that @MatthewDaws has referred to, but that might be one place to look

Comment: Basically, my intuition is that $M(X)$ is an $L_1$-ish kind of space, and you don't expect the injective tensor product of two $L^1$-ish things to be $L^1$-ish -- $\ell^1$ plays well with projective tensor product instead. Dually, the projective tensor product of two $C(K)$-ish things won't be $C(K)$-ish, in general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me work with general Banach spaces (good references are [Vector Measures](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0453964) by Diestel and Uhl, or [Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1888309) by Ryan).

For Banach spaces $E,F$ the bounded bilinear maps on $E\times F$ can be identified with the dual space of $E \hat\otimes_\pi F$ (this is a special case of the universal property of the norm $\pi$) which in turn can be identified with $B(E,F^*)$ in the obvious way.  The injective tensor norm agrees with the norm induced by embedding $E^*\otimes F^*$ into $B(E,F^*)$; the closure is the *approximable operators*.  As $M(X)$ has the (metric) [approximation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property) we find that $M(X) \hat\otimes_\epsilon M(Y)$ is the *compact* operators from $C(X) \rightarrow M(Y)$.

> An example where $M(X) \hat\otimes_\epsilon M(Y)$ is not the bounded bilinear maps on $C(X) \times C(Y)$.

Let $X=Y=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure and consider $T:C(X) \rightarrow L^1(X) \subseteq M(X)$.  By considering e.g. the functions $f_n(t) = \exp(2\pi itn)$ we see that $T$ is not compact.

> Furthermore, we **do not** have that $M(X\times Y) \subseteq M(X) \hat\otimes_\epsilon M(Y) = K(C(X),M(Y))$.

Again let $X=Y=[0,1]$ and let $\mu\in M(X\times Y)$ be
$$ \langle \mu, f \rangle = \int_{[0,1]} f(t,t) \ dt \qquad (f\in C([0,1]^2) $$
so $\mu(E\times F) = |E\cap F|$ the Lesbegue measure of $E\cap F$, for $E,F\subseteq [0,1]$ measurable.  This *does* induce a bounded linear map $T:C([0,1]) \rightarrow M([0,1])$ by
$$ \langle T(f), g \rangle = \langle \mu, f\otimes g \rangle
= \int_{[0,1]} f(t) g(t) \ dt \qquad (f,g \in C([0,1])). $$
But this is just the same $T$ as I considered above: the inclusion of $C([0,1])$ into $L^1([0,1]) \subseteq M([0,1])$; this is not compact.

> This $\mu \in M(X\times Y)$ is also an example of an element not in $M(X) \hat\otimes_\pi M(Y)$.

I don't know an elementary way to see this; but the theory is interesting.  Again see the references at the start.  A *vector measure* $\lambda$ on a measure space $X$ is a countably additive map $\lambda:X\rightarrow E$, for a Banach space $E$.  $\lambda$ is regular if $\varphi\circ\lambda\in M(X)$ is regular for each $\varphi\in E^*$.  Every *weakly compact* operator $T:C(X)\rightarrow E$ has the form
$$ T(f) = \int_X f \ d\lambda \qquad (f\in C(X)), $$
for a regular vector measure $\lambda$.

Let $\lambda_0$ be a finite positive measure on $X$.  Then $\lambda$ is *absolutely continuous* with respect to $\lambda_0$ exactly when $\lambda_0(E)=0 \implies \lambda(E)=0$.  Say that $\lambda$ has the *Radon-Nikodym* property if, whenever $\lambda$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda_0$, then $\lambda = \int F \ d\lambda_0$ for some *Bochner integrable* $F:X\rightarrow E$.  (The point is that not all vector measures have this property, in contrast to the scale case).  An operator $T:C(X)\rightarrow E$ comes from some member of $M(X) \hat\otimes_\pi E$ (that is, is a *nuclear* operator) if and only if the representing vector measure has the Radon-Nikodym property.

Again with $X=Y=[0,1]$ with $\mu$ and $T$ as before, the associated vector measure $\lambda:[0,1]\rightarrow M([0,1])$ is
$$ \lambda(E) : F \mapsto |E\cap F| $$
for measurable $E,F\subseteq [0,1]$.  This is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.  If $F:[0,1]\rightarrow M([0,1])$ is a Bochner integrable function inducing $\lambda$ then
$$ \langle \lambda(E), f \rangle = \int_E f(t) \ dt =
\int_E \langle F(s), f \rangle \ ds \qquad (f\in C([0,1])). $$
Thus $F(s) = \delta_s$ the point-mass at $s$, for all $s\in [0,1]$.  However, by the [Pettis Measurability Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_measurable_function), $F$ should be *essentially separably valued* but clearly this is not the case, giving the required contradiction.

My *guess* would be that you can boost this example up to show that $M(X)\hat\otimes_\pi M(Y)$ is strictly contained in $M(X\times Y)$ unless one of $X$ or $Y$ is discrete (in which case we do have equality).

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! What puzzles me here: Isn't it obvious that the $\mu$ you consider is not in $\mathcal{M}(X)\hat{\otimes}_\pi \mathcal{M}(Y)$ from the fact that it is not in $\mathcal{M}(X)\hat{\otimes}_\varepsilon \mathcal{M}(Y)$?

Comment: No, you are completely correct!!  I wrote the 2nd half first, and didn't go back to check...  But I guess it's nice that you can completely characterise $M(X) \hat\otimes\pi M(Y)$ in terms of vector measures.

Comment: See my edit above. Having seen your answer, I cannot help but wonder, if $\mathcal{M} \hat{\otimes}_\varepsilon \mathcal{M}(Y)$ is contained in $\mathcal{M}(X \times Y)$ and whether the latter is contained in $\mathrm{Bil}(C(X) \times C(Y))$.